# What is the weakness of Beautifulsoup4 in term of scraping item like HTML?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have little project with beautiful soup to scrape some item in url : https://www.bukalapak.com/flash-deal.

What I want to do is to scrape item :

- item solds
- price
- item left

I already have some basic Bs4 logic. but I cant scrape that 3 thing. after I check on HTML tree, the list of item is not found.
When I inspect element on that site, i did find the data, but cant retrieve it via BS4.

the question is, is that true I assume that Bs4 cannot scrape item that are not in HTML tree ?

Comment: BS can't run `JavaScript` which can add items on page.

Comment: BS4 parses HTML. Nothing more, nothing less. It obviously can’t parse what isn’t there. You’re probably looking for a headless browser which can interpret Javascript too.

Comment: for that case, use selenium because there's `JS` need to be rendered

Comment: @furas ahh i see. thanks

Comment: @deceze, same as above answer. thankyou

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη okay, many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The site is populated with the content from an API-call. I'm not exactly sure how often they change the key but it seems like there is another API-call you can make to get a valid authentication-key:

```
import requests
token = requests.get("https://seller.bukalapak.com/api/authenticate").json()['token']
```

Use this to call their store's API, i.e.

```
resp = requests.get("https://api.bukalapak.com/_exclusive/flash-deals/campaigns/2653/products?access_token=" + token).json()
```

They use different campaign-ids, e.g. 2653, 2662, 2635, ... and I don't know how they create them and if they change (try replacing *2653* in above call - they somehow correspond to the different starting times). Maybe you have enough domain knowledge to create them. You can find them when inspecting the network calls (e.g. in your browser).

Comment: thankyou fo your answer, i probably need to user selenium